# Hibernate exception when setting the @joinedColumn(table) property to an entity class that extends another entiry class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following scenario:

Entity Command:

```
@Entity
public class Command {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(nullable=false)
private Date timeOfExecution;

--constructors, getters, setters...--
```

Entity CmdTest that extends Command:

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTable(name = "CmdTest")
public class CmdTest extends Command{

    @Column(table = "CmdTest", nullable = false)
    private String testParam;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(table="CmdTest")
    private Citizen citizen;

    -- getters, setters, construcotr --
}
```

Entity Citizen:

```
@Entity
public class Citizen {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="citizen")
    private CmdTest cmdTest;

    -- getters, setters, constructor --
}
```

As you can see, I have a bidirectional relationship between Citizen and CmdTest.
I want to persist citizen first, and then the CmdTest.

I am using a web service to call initTest() method of MyBean. MyBean creates a Citizen and a CmdTest instance and then tries to persist the citizen first, and then the CmdTest.

Here is my initTest() method:

```
public void initTest() {

    CmdTest cmd = new CmdTest();
    cmd.setTestParam("asd");
    cmd.setTimeOfExecution(new Date());

    Citizen citizen = new Citizen();
    citizen.setName("John Doe");

    citizen.setCmdTest(cmd);
    cmd.setCitizen(citizen);

    em.persist(citizen);
    em.persist(cmd);

}
```

By setting @JoinColumn(table="CmdTest") on citizen field I try to tell JPA to persist citizen_id foreign key inside CmdTest table, if I comment out that line, everything works fine, but I get citizen_id foreign key inside the Command table.

When I put @JoinColumn(table="CmdTest") I get the following exception: `Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation`

I know I could persist the CmdTest first to put the transient CmdTest object in persistence context, and then the Citizen and it would work. I tried it.

But, I want to know, why is this not working? Is it a bug in Hibernate or JPA? I can't seem to find the reason...

Answer (score 0):

You got this exception because you were trying to save `citizen` object with a reference to `cmd` object, while you didn't persisted the `cmd` instance to the database.

That's how hibernate works, it persisits and manages objects in the database, when it tries to persist the `citizen` instance it finds that it was mapped to an object (`cmd`), when it tries to construct this relationship in the db, it will look for the respective `cmd` object, using `id`, but it won't find it won't find it  that's why you will get the Exception `Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation` as the `cmd` wasn't persisted.

You need to `persist/save` the `cmd` object to DB before trying saving `citizen` object, this is how should be your code:

```
public void initTest() {

    CmdTest cmd = new CmdTest();
    cmd.setTestParam("asd");
    cmd.setTimeOfExecution(new Date());

    Citizen citizen = new Citizen();
    citizen.setName("John Doe");

    em.persist(cmd);

    citizen.setCmdTest(cmd);
    cmd.setCitizen(citizen);

    em.persist(citizen);
}
```

So this isn't a bug in `Hibernate`, but this is how it's intended to work you can't map an object to another `transient` (not `persisited`) one.

Comment: I know I could do it like that. Read my whole question. But, how do you explain that my code works when I remove the table="CmdTest" from my @joinColumn annotation? That way, it works no matter what I persist first. I am curious why?

Comment: @user3362334 No this isn't a bug, that's how hibernate works, please take a look at the explanation in my Edit.

Comment: Read again. Try and test it. Take my code and remove table="CmdTest" parameter from @joinColumn and it works. Please, explain why? So, in that case I still have the bidirectional association between cmd and citizen and I still persist the citizen object while it is mapped to the cmd(just in this scenario in db it is stored in the parent class Command instead), and it still works. And I don't change the order of persisting, I still persist the citizen first. Try it out. It just works. And I don't understand why?